# Group buttons aesthetically in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgroupbox

I want to do something like this:

[image]

I'm not being able to find any way to group the buttons like that. Namely, to enclose them in rectangles and put a 'title' to that 'button section'.

Is it possible to do this in PyQt5?

Comment: Take a look at [QGroupBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html).  I believe it is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `QGroupBox` next to a `QToolButton` and a `QLabel`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

data = [{
        "title": " Y Axis Variables",
        "buttons": [{
                "text": "Add/Quit/Modify",
                "path_icon": "Add.png"
            },
            {
                "text": "Calculate Var",
                "path_icon": "calculate.png"
            },
            {
                "text": "Delete Cal Var",
                "path_icon": "delete.png"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Project",
        "buttons": [{
                "text": "Save",
                "path_icon": "save.png"
            },
            {
                "text": "Add Tab",
                "path_icon": "add.png"
            }
        ]
    }
]


class ToolButton(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, path_icon, parent=None):
        super(ToolButton, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        toolButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(path_icon))
        toolButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(text)
        lay.addWidget(toolButton, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)


class GroupButton(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, info, parent=None):
        super(GroupButton, self).__init__(parent)
        title = info["title"]
        self.setTitle(title)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        for info_button in info["buttons"]:
            text = info_button["text"]
            path_icon = info_button["path_icon"]
            btn = ToolButton(text, path_icon)
            hlay.addWidget(btn)
        hlay.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        for val in data:
            gb = GroupButton(val)
            hlay.addWidget(gb)
        hlay.addStretch()
        vlay.addLayout(hlay)
        vlay.addStretch()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you use `QToolButton` instead of `QPushButton`? I'm having trouble connecting the formers with functions, as they don't have a `connect()` method as the latters. How can a function be called when pressing a `QToolButton`?

Comment: @Tendero QToolButton allows you to display an icon so I choose it, if you want to see the difference use a QPushButton. On the other hand, QPushButton and QToolButton inherit from QAbstractButton, and QAbstractButton has the clicked signal, so QToolButton and QPushButton share the signal.

Comment: But when I do `btn.clicked.connect(self.func)` Python returns the following error: `AttributeError: 'ToolButton' object has no attribute 'clicked'`.

Comment: @Tendero ToolButton is not QToolButton, QToolButton is toolButton inside ToolButton, check the code well, 
Do you understand my code?

Comment: Ah, I see, I got confused. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. Is there a way to shrink the size of the group? I mean, I want the rectangle that encloses the buttons to have less free-space in it. Is this possible?

Comment: you could explain yourself better, maybe if you show me an edited image of what you want to get you could help

Comment: Check [this image](https://imgur.com/a/b45LZA1). The picture on the top is what I'm getting using your code. Below is what I'd like: more narrow groups in height, with less free-space in them.

Comment: use setContentsMargins() as I show in my updated response. 
On the other hand this will be the last comment I answer on this thread, if you want another question create a new post.